# Use hidden information for filtering data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I filter information - let's say I want to see only Panasonic computers. Is it possible that information begin from 1 to 1000? NOT 1,12,13,14,50,57,100. Because in my case, hidden information doesn't let me use formulas from other sheet.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try a pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used pivot table as Matt said :)